# Save the console text into a txt file? (PHP)

Tags: php, shell, console

actual I finished writing my program. Because it is only a plugin and it runs on a external server I still want to see if I get some errors or something else in the console.

I wrote every console input with `echo ...;`. My question now is if it is possible to get the text of the console?

Because then I could easily safe it in a .txt file and could get access to it from the web :) - Or is there another way to get the console text?

I could probably just say `fwrite(...)` instand of `echo ...;`. But this will cost a lot of time...

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: How do you execute your script? You could just do something like "php myscript.php >> mylog.log" and all the `echo` will be stored inside the log.

Comment: I execute it with an cronjob by my hoster in an interface

Comment: Then just add the `>> logfilename.log` at the end of your command.

Comment: Which command ?

Comment: To get STDOUT and STDERR into the log do `php myscript.php >> mylog.log  2>&1`

Comment: I have only an interface where I can click "Run Cronjob"

Comment: I can add arguments. But nothing more...

Comment: If you can't access the real crontab do this in your script on line 1: `ob_start(); register_shutdown_function(function(){ file_put_contents('mylog.txt',ob_get_clean()); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative that could be usefull on windows would be to save all the output buffer to a txt, first check your php configuration for the console app  implicit_flush must be off then

```
<?php  
ob_start(); //before any echo
/** YOUR CODE HERE **/
$output = ob_get_contents(); //this variable has all the echoes
file_put_contents('c:\whatever.txt',$output);
ob_flush(); //shows the echoes on console
?>
```

Comment: Only on Windows or does it works also on a Linux Server?

Comment: it works on linux too but on linux you can simple run:

php yourscript.php > path/to/log.txt

and that makes the job without changing a single line of php code

Answer (score 1):

For console (commando line interface) you can redirect the output of your script:

```
php yourscript.php > path-of-your-file.txt
```

If you haven't access to a command line interface or to edit the cronjob line, you can duplicate the starndar output at the begining of the script:

```
$fdout = fopen('path-to-your-script.txt', 'wb');
eio_dup2($fdout, STDOUT);
eio_event_loop();
fclose($fdout);
```

(eio is an pecl extension)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to create a text file to access, then you should create a text file directly.

(do this instead of echoing to console)

```
$output  = $consoleData . "\n";
$output .= $moreConsoleData . "\n";
```

(Once you've completed that, just create the file:)

```
$file = fopen('output.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($file, $output);
    fclose($file);
```

Of course, this is sparse - you should also check that the file exists, create it if necessary, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the script using the console (i.e. php yourscript.php), you can easily save the output my modifying your command to:

```
php yourscript.php > path/to/log.txt
```

The above command will capture all output by the script and save it to `log.txt`. Change the paths for your script / log as required.